# Sed out word after specific word and /

Tags: sed, grep

I am using grep to search out `/Users/` in a text file. This is the output:

```
'dir': u'/Users/dlee/Desktop',
```

Is there a way to sed out the word after `Users/`?  That is, to get `dlee` as the output?

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?  Is it the slashes that are causing you trouble?  Note that `sed` can find the line as well as extract the information.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
sed -n '\@.*/Users/\([^/]*\)/.*@ s//\1/p' text.file
```

The `-n` suppresses output unless data is printed explicitly.  The `\@` notation replaces the search character (default `/`) with `@`.  Then the search pattern looks for `/Users/` followed by a sequence of non-slashes and a slash, capturing the non-slashes (user name); it matches everything else on the line too (the `.*` at beginning and end).  The `s//\1`/p` command replaces what was matched (the whole line) with what was captured (the user name), and prints the information.

Alternatively, you can use a backslash-slash sequence to match the slashes in the data:

```
sed -n '/.*\/Users\/\([^/]*\)\/.*/ s//\1/p' text.file
```

You do not need a backslash before the slash in the character class, but the other backslashes are needed.  If you were unwise enough to have a user name `d\lee` and you included a backslash in the character class, you would not see the name `d\lee` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, you could also use awk to do achieve the same.

```
awk -F"/" '/Users/{print $2}' file
```

The delimiter has been set to `/` which will print the second column on rows containing the string "`Users`".

Answer (score 0):

With grep and Perl regex:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=/Users/)[^/]*' <<< "'dir': u'/Users/dlee/Desktop',"
dlee
```

- `-o` returns only the match
- `(?<=/Users/)` is a "positive look-behind", i.e., the match has to be preceded by it but it is not included
- `[^/]*` is any number of characters except forward slashes