# Find every word with grep beginning with /dev/, containing any character after that until a space

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Let's say the input is something like this:

> /dev/sda1 something something word word /dev/sda4/ something word word

I want to achieve this output using grep:

> /dev/sda1 /dev/sda4

I currently have this: `grep -o "\/dev\/"`, but it only prints /dev/, and not the rest of the word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep for the whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2879085/608639), [Extract only whole word using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17616012/608639), [How to search for whole words with grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32066451/608639), [Why doesn't grep match a forward-slash at word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47743394/608639), [grep string including forward slash as part of word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49369046/608639), [Sed out word after specific word and /](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35282018/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match characters that aren't in a given set of characters like this:

```
grep -o "/dev/[^ ]*"
```

(Edited to remove the unnecessary backslashes.)

Comment: Do not use `\/`, use `/`. `grep` patterns do not use regex delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even see that those were in there.